# Out-of-nowhere ClassCastException in android

Tags: java, android, reflection, ormlite

This morning I woke up on this strange exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.lang.reflect.ImplForVariable cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Class

It happens when I try to get a Type argument Class.

Example:

```
public static Class getTypeParameterClass(Object o, int index) {
    return (Class)
            ((ParameterizedType)o.getClass()
                    .getGenericSuperclass())
                    .getActualTypeArguments()[index];
}
```

As you can see, this method gets one of the type parameter for a given object's class.

It's been working for months now but today, it stopped.

Usage example:

```
Collection<Object> foo = new ArrayList<Object>();

Class<?> fooClass = Utils.getTypeParameterClass(foo, 0);
```

And it crashes.

Is there a curse on me for blaming java too many times;) ?

Thanks !

Comment: After reinstalling my IDE/sdk/ndk/jdk I still have that bug, I suspect some sort of configuration errors. Still need to try on a different computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of all, let me address a huge "thank you" to Gray for his patience.

I finally figured what was wrong.

I was focusing on the wrong field.

So, as Gray points out, because of type erasure you can't get a type parameter that is not explicitly given at compile time.

I was so persuaded that the error was on a Collection field that I totally forgot about other fields.

So, because my data come from webservices, and because the JSON mapper can't directly get a list as root, I had to define models containing a Collection of objects, a date (for caching) and few other things related to paging.

So, because writing all these similar classes was a nonsense, I tried to generalize the process, like so:

```
public abstract class ModelList<T> {

        [ paging and caching stuffs ]

        @ForeignCollectionField
        Collection<T> collection;

        [ constructor, getters, setters ]

}
```

and then only have subclasses like:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "category_list")
public class CategoryList extends ModelList<Category> {

}
```

So I could have less verbose classes, and so I could generalize the caching process using ObjectPersister from Robospice.

What I couldn't understand (because of a lack of knowledge), is that the  parameter would not be found at run time !

What confused me even more is that the tests I ran to try to reproduce the bug, WERE producing the bug ! but they were wrong too.

So, note to self (and others that may face complete nonsense like I did):

- don't lose faith in the language (it's not buggy, it's not buggy, it's not buggy ...)
- don't blame the language (not too much)
- always attach sources to jars and set breakpoints

At the end the solution was quite simple, just move the collection from the ModelList to the sublasses, and keep the getters and setters as abstract methods in ModelList (for the generic ObjectPersisters).

I think it all got a little too complicated, if someone knows a better solution for this case using ormlite/jackson/robospice I'd be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see, this method gets one of the type parameter for a given object's class.

So what you are doing is specifically not allowed because of the generic type erasure.  You are trying to investigate the generic parameter of your `ArrayList` but when the code is running, the specific generic type is no longer visible.

Your superclass hack (and it is a hack) would work if you were dealing with a superclass.  It would work if you defined your `ArrayList` like:

```
Collection<Object> foo = new ArrayList<Object>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -594043150300376049L;
};
```

In this case `foo` is a class which *extends* `ArraryList`.  For some reason with the superclass the generic type parameter is available.

Comment: Hi Gray, looks like you are answering the question I posted on the ormlite-android github, actually I realized the issue is nothing related to ormlite, but something screwed android runtime for my app, thus reflectivity is f*cked up too.. I tried on a separate building environment and it doesn't work either. Now my last hope is to re-create my intelliJ project, and just hope for it to fix the bug. Anyway I'd still like to understand what got screwed ! thanks anyway.

Comment: Update, I recreated the project from scratch, and I still have the crash... I'm now totally out of solutions.